# Is there an alternative way to pass level 4?

Tags: eversion

I've found the 4th level of eversion quite frustrating, mostly due to the giant hands.
In the middle of the level there's this tricky part:

[image: jump]

I'm trying to do the jump to reach the platform on the right, but I usually end up hitting the hand in the point indicated. Is there a less painful way to pass this part? Alternatively, is there a jumping trick to make it easier?

Comment: This might be dumb, because I haven't played the game, but is there no way to just go over the top, where those purple spheres with eyes are?

Comment: @AshleyNunn yes, you can go on the left, but those jumps are as difficult as the one I'm trying, with the added danger of more enemies (the purple spheres up there are actually moving enemies that kill you on touch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: no, there is no other way. But it is possible to jump directly to the floor from you position. To do so you have to tap the jump button since pressing it longer results in a higher jump. I have just tried it and succeeded at the second attempt ;)